# Store any UTF8 coded HTML source code in a MariaDB/MySQL UTF-8 table without issues with "<" (&lt;)

Tags: php, html, utf-8, mariadb, html-entities

I'm using PHP to store HTML5 code in a Maria database. Before store in database the HMTL5 content, I decode entities with

```
$Uncoded_content = mysqli_real_escape_string($database_link, html_entity_decode($HTML5_content,ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5 ,'UTF-8'));
```

Where $HTML_content is the HTML5 source code, with entities coded.

I was mad when suddenly, after months without any kind of problem storing all kind of characters (included "<", apostrophes, quotes, etc), I saw in an HTML table, in which cells there are some "<" symbols in formulas) that some text simply was not showed. After inspecting the stored content in database, the HTML code was fine, undecoded and with all characters. Finally, I discovered that if **I don't leave a space just before and after the "<" symbols**, web browsers make disappear some texts. It's clear that browser is interpreting that "<" as opening a tag.

Here is the HTML5 source code content, as it's stored in database.

```html
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="570">
  <tr>
    <td>Zona lumínica</td>
    <td>Superficie del cartel</td>
    <td>Luminancia máxima (cd/m2)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E1</td>
    <td>n/a</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E2</td>
    <td>n/a</td>
    <td>400</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">E3</td>
    <td>S
      <2m<sup>2</sup>
    </td>
    <td>800</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2
      <S≤10m<sup>2</sup>
    </td>
    <td>600</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>S>10m<sup>2</sup></td>
    <td>400</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4">E4</td>
    <td>S
      <0,5m<sup>2</sup>
    </td>
    <td>1.000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0,5
      <S≤2m<sup>2</sup>
    </td>
    <td>800</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2
      <S≤10m<sup>2</sup>
    </td>
    <td>600</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>S>10m<sup>2</sup></td>
    <td>400</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p><br /><br /></p>
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="570">
  <tr>
    <td>Zona lumínica</td>
    <td>Superficie del cartel</td>
    <td>Luminancia máxima (cd/m2)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E1</td>
    <td>n/a</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E2</td>
    <td>n/a</td>
    <td>400</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">E3</td>
    <td>S
      < 2m<sup>2</sup>
    </td>
    <td>800</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2
      < S ≤ 10m<sup>2</sup>
    </td>
    <td>600</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>S > 10m<sup>2</sup></td>
    <td>400</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4">E4</td>
    <td>S
      < 0,5m<sup>2</sup>
    </td>
    <td>1.000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0,5
      < S ≤ 2m<sup>2</sup>
    </td>
    <td>800</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2
      < S ≤ 10m<sup>2</sup>
    </td>
    <td>600</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>S > 10m<sup>2</sup></td>
    <td>400</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Both tables are identical except second table has spaces before and after each "<" that appears as raw text CONTENT in some cells. The first table have no those spaces.

When I do a simple "echo"

```
echo $HTML5_source_content
```

from PHP of that content (in an HTML5 structure), the first table is showed with some text hided. The second table is showed completely, as it should. To avoid this issue, I tried:

```
echo htmlentities($HTML5_source_content, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8");
```

But in this case, browser doesn't not show the parsed HTML source, but the source itself (the rest of the page is showed as HTML). I tried even with "htmlspecialchars" but same result, the source code.

What am I forgetting? Where is my error?

Please, any help is welcome

Thank you

Comment: Why are you storing HTML in a database?

Comment: You're focusing on the wrong part of the pipeline. Your data (HTML) is already mangled. (Obvs escaping the whole document will, well, escape the whole document.) Focus on the place where you _generate_ that HTML. Or ideally, store your information semantically rather than in this "rendered" form.

Comment: _Why_ do you decode entities for storage??

Comment: And why are you using `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead of prepared statements with `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`?

Comment: You should only be encoding entities that you wish to remain encoded, not the entire chunk of HTML. I.e. encode only the characters like "<" which you intend to be rendered verbatim.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 I'm storing it in database to improve search inside content.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 I decode entities for same reason: I need to make searchs in content in many european languages, so I need so search "Ramón" and not "Ram&oacute;". Data storage space is another reason.

Comment: @Barmar I'm using mysqli_real_escape_string to force characters like simple and double quotes and apostrophes in the text will be stored like simple characters, as I need to let user to search that characters too.

Comment: @kmoser Before asking here, I tried `htmlspecialchars` too (to not encode all entities), but the issue is exactly the same. No difference in the incorrect output I described.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 In my case, to have content stored "as is" in HTML is a must: People who write our articles works with HTML editor software and it need to be stored that way. I understand that some usual software as WordPress possibly works same way.

Comment: @RafaelLinuxUser Then you are stuck. And WordPress probably does _not_ store big HTML documents like this.

Comment: @RafaelLinuxUser If you use a prepared statement with bound parameters, that also stores the characters normally.

Comment: @RafaelLinuxUser As others have already pointed out, the issue is that you want some characters like "<" to be interpreted as HTML in some cases but not others, but you are not indicating that when you are storing the entire chunk of text. So when the chunk of text gets interpreted by the browser, it interprets *everything* as HTML. *The fundamental flaw in your approach is that you are failing to indicate which character(s) to treat as literals and which to treat as HTML.* It has nothing to do with the database itself.

Comment: I'm working in a function in PHP to make entities only the character"<" when is not part of an (X)HTML tag. Is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

It's not strange behaviour; it's what you asked your computer to do. You asked it to store an HTML document, and then to make searching work you asked it to decode *all* the entities in the HTML document, causing (in some cases) the meaning of the document to change, and causing (in the worst cases) your document to become invalid.

Don't store HTML in your database. You should generate HTML for rendering, not for storage. Store your data semantically. (MySQL has text search capabilities; HTML just makes that *harder*.)

Storing it in presentation markup format, and stripping away all the contextual information (by decoding entities) has left you with data you cannot reliably use. When you had `&lt;`, you now have `<`, and there's no way to know which was which before you bulk-decoded all the entities.

**You put milk into water and stirred. You can't get the water back.**

You need to come to the understanding that your approach is fundamentally flawed. You should examine each step in your decision making process and explain it to yourself again.

Then store nice normal strings in your database, not HTML.

If for some reason that is impossible, at least stop decoding entities. That will make searching a bit harder, as a simple text search will not be sufficient, but actually your search routine *should* be HTML-aware anyway in order to get correct results, so you may as well get that right.

---

tl;dr:

> It's clear that browser is interpreting that "<" as opening a tag.

Because it is. That's what `<` does in HTML.

It was fine as `&lt;` but then you unescaped it.

Comment: There must be any way to store HTML in database, I'm sure, but I don't know how to avoid this issue. Maybe I should change my question title, cause will be more generic and less specific to a entity.

Comment: I have spoken. Sorry you don't like the answer but that's the situation you're in. Changing the title won't change the answer.

Comment: Well, I solved my problem (you will see behind) but I must say that as you can see in my question, I DO escaped the HTML content. You maybe wanted to write "decoded the HTML entity"  ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seemed not easy, but consulting other ideas to solve similar problems, I coded this script, and it solves my headaches to store any HTML content to MariaDB/MySQL database (UTF-8 tables) and retrieve to show as UTF-8 webpage without issues. In my case, users paste text from word processors, so many times they have typographic characters (double and single quotes) and we replace them with non-typographic ones to let users search them too.

```
function PREPARE_TO_STORE($HTML_Code)
{
    $V_Matches = Array();
    $Token = '###TOKEN_HTML###';
    // We will replace typographic characters by non typographical ones and will remain "<" as an HTML entity
    $V_Search  = array( "‘", "’", "”", "“", "″", "<");  
    $V_Replace = array( "'", "'", '"', '"', '"', "&lt;");

    preg_match_all("@<[^>]*>@", $HTML_Code, $V_Matches);
    $V_Content = preg_replace("@(<[^>]*>)@", $Token, $HTML_Code); // $V_Content will contain string between HTML tags
    $V_Content = explode($Token, $V_Content); // Splits HTML from content 

    for ($i=0; $i<count($V_Content); $i++) // Decoding all entities
    {
       $V_Content[$i] = html_entity_decode($V_Content[$i], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8");
       $V_Content[$i] = str_replace($V_Search, $V_Replace, $V_Content[$i]);
    }
    $V_Content = join($Token, $V_Content); // Join again HTML tags with content        

    for ($i=0; $i<count($V_Matches[0]); $i++)  
        $V_Content = preg_replace("@$Token@", $V_Matches[0][$i], $V_Content, 1);
    return $V_Content;
}

$HTML_to_store_in_db = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,  PREPARE_TO_STORE($anuncio));

// Here your own code to store $HTML_to_store_in_db in your database
```

To show our stored HTML code, simply we do:

```
echo $HTML_data_retrieved_from_DB;
```

but if your web page is not in UTF-8, maybe you need to do

```
echo htmlspecialchars($HTML_data_retrieved_from_DB, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, "webpage_coding");  // "webpage_coding" is your character coding, in our case, UTF-8
```

Any suggestions, questions or fixes are welcome, of course

Thank you to all you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the HTML code from the authors as is and want to output it on the page as "working" HTML code, then you don't use any HTML encode/decode function. Save the received content "as is" in the database and output the HTML later "as is" normally with `echo`, just like it was a "normal" content without HTML code. Keep in mind that this is a huge security issue since the authors could write any HTML code they like with their HTML editor software. They can add any HTML code, including javascript code. You have been warned!

For the HTML entities which could be replaced to their respective character (like `&oacute;` to `ó`), use the [`get_html_translation_table()`](http://www.php.net/get_html_translation_table) function to get a mapping of these characters. Subtract the mapping `HTML_SPECIALCHARS` from the mapping `HTML_ENTITIES` because you only want the non-HTML related mapping. Use the [`array_diff()`](http://www.php.net/array_diff) method to do so. With the mapping fire up a simple `str_replace()` call to replace all the entities with their characters.

```
$text = '<b>Ram&oacute;n</b>, formula <code>a &lt; b</code>, <a href="link.html">some link</a> content. Some&nbsp;spaced&nbsp;words.';
$mapping = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);
$mapping = array_diff($mapping, get_html_translation_table());

echo $text."\n";
echo str_replace(array_values($mapping), array_keys($mapping), $text);
```

For testing purposes, this will generate the following output:

```
<b>Ram&oacute;n</b>, formula <code>a &lt; b</code>, <a href="link.html">some link</a> content. Some&nbsp;spaced&nbsp;words.
<b>Ramón</b>, formula <code>a &lt; b</code>, <a href="link.html">some link</a> content. Some spaced words.
```

As you see the HTML related entities stays as entities and the other entities gets replaced by their characters. Apply this conversion before saving the original HTML code into your database.

For the already decoded HTML content in your database: you are out of luck. There is no fool-proof way to "reencode" the HTML related characters like `<` back to their `&lt;` entity as you don't know which one was/is HTML code and which one was/is "content". You can make good guesses like

> The text `< b` should be `&lt; b` and the text `<b` should stay as it is because that is HTML code.

but this is still just (good/bad) guessing.

Comment: I read before about `get_html_translation_table()` but it seemed to me that was a too complicated way to store HTML in database. After reading your explanation, I can understand that will be the only way. In the past, we hadn't problems to store HTML, till source documents began to include logical comparisons like "<" or ">"  or non Spanish characters, like apostrophes or foreign names. Then, problems appeared.

I'll try tomorrow your elaborated and detailed explanation and will report results here.

As you wrote, previously stored HTML data need a special attention.

THANK YOU

Comment: @RafaelLinuxUser `get_html_translation_table()` is not required to store HTML in the database. It is only used so you can search for "Ramón" (based on your comments) when the original HTML code contained only `Ram&oacute;n`. When you don't replace the entities you still can save the HTML code in the database and output it as usual.

Comment: Thank you Progman, I misunderstood your explanation. To store as entities is not exactly my preferred option, cause in fact database and table are in utf8mb4 to store any Unicode character to make searches easier, so we are wasting 4 bytes for nothing if moreover I store each entity as a code sequence. I'll study another options.